# Drawing an oriented curve with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to make the graph of this curve with Tikz; I am not quite sure how to do the diagram, detailing of the arrows and points. I would really appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost literally copied from section 50.6.1 of the pgf manual.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings,% switch on markings
    mark=between positions 0.1 and 0.9 step 12mm with {\arrow{stealth}}},
    dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill}]
  \draw[postaction={decorate},red] (0,0) node[dot,label=right:{$P_2(2,2)$}]{}
    arc[start angle=45,end angle=-135,radius=2] 
    node[dot,label=left:{$P_2(-2,-2)$}]{}
    -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My post overlapped with yours. But I see you did essentially the same thing I did. May I suggest placing the decorations into its own style with `tikzset` as I did in my solution? I will delete mine since it's so similar and you posted first. Also, you may want to add the `\gamma` label to the arc.

Comment: @SandyG Thanks for the heads up! I do not see a reason why you want to remove your nice answer. As for the style, yes, you can define a global style, and in many situations this is precisely what you want. However, there can also be a benefit from having the definition local, which the example in the pgf manual and this answer does.

Answer (score 4):

It is often useful to use `\tikzset` for a style you will use more than once. In the code below, adding `multarrow` to `\draw` options will add five arrows to the path.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{multarrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0.1 and 1 step 0.2 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[multarrow, red, thick] (-2,-2)node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label={[below left] $P_1(-2,-2)$}]{} 
  -- (2,2)node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label={[right] $P_2(2,2)$}]{} 
  arc(45:-135:{2*sqrt(2)})node[below right, pos=.3]{$\gamma$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```